# Migrating ZF2 to ZF3: Hot to convert the "realServiceLocator"?

Tags: zend-framework2, migration, service-locator, zend-framework3, zend-servicemanager

In the `Factory` classes of my Zend Framework 2 application, I often used such a construction:

```
// The signature was actually wrong, since it was always the `AbstractPluginManager` (or the `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager` for the "common" services) and not just `ServiceLocator`, and it also was used as `AbstractPluginManager` (or `ServiceManager` for the "common" services). The `ServiceLocatorInterface` did not provide the `getServiceLocator()` method.
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    // the common ServiceLocator
    $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
    $myServiceFoo = $realServiceLocator->get('My\Service\Foo');
    $myServiceBar = new \My\Service\Bar($myServiceFoo);
    ...
}
```

So to access a "common" service, I first retrieved the `ServiceLocator`. This approach was necessary in factories for `Hydrator`s, `Controller`s, and other services, that have their own `ServiceManager`s. Because for them the input `ServiceLocator` was `AbstractPluginManager` and not the `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager`.

Now I made the first migration step for my factories and replaced some common things:

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    // the common ServiceLocator
    $realServiceLocator = $container->getServiceLocator();
    $myServiceFoo = $realServiceLocator->get('My\Service\Foo');
    $myServiceBar = new \My\Service\Bar($myServiceFoo);
    ...
}
```

**How to adapt the `$container->getServiceLocator()` to the ZF3?**

Comment: It's worth looking at the migrations guide for ZF3 service manager, the plugin manager section explains how plugin managers have changed, http://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/migration/#plugin-managers In the AbstractPluginManager section (the class from which all of zends component plugin managers inherit) it explains that the constructor now accepts the parent container instance as first argument; this is usually the application-level ServiceManager instance". In the case of ZF plugin managers you get the `$realServiceLocator` as the `$container` in your plugin factories

Answer (score 3):

`getServiceLocator()` is deprecated so you can not use this one in ZF3. You would be able to make the service manager available using an instance of `Interop\Container\ContainerInterface` while making factories as the following

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $myServiceFoo = $container->get('My\Service\Foo');
    $myServiceBar = new \My\Service\Bar($myServiceFoo);
    ...
}
```